# Rails 4 - current_page? with query parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've method in my application.rb

```
def current_page(path)
  "active" if current_page?(path)
end
```

then in my view, lets say the request_uri is http://www.example.com/stories, i just can call

```
<%= link_to "All Stories", stories_path, :class => "#{current_page(stories_path)}" %>
```

BUT how about if the request_uri has something like http://www.example.com/stories?featured=true ? How do I call it in view?

Answer (score 0):

Because `current_page?` method will compare passed-in path which doesn't have `?` just with your current url deleting query params.

For example, if you're at `http://www.example.com/stories?featured=true`, and you have `current_page(stories_path)`, you'll still compare `http://www.example.com/stories`(stories_path) with `http://www.example.com/stories`(your current url without `featured=true`).

I have a idea, but you'll have `?` in the end of your normal url.You can change the code to `<%= link_to "All Stories", stories_path + '?', :class => "#{current_page(stories_path + "?")}" %>`

I'll update this if I come up with better methods.

Comment: Yeah I did that

    <%= link_to "All Stories", stories_path, :class => "#{current_page(stories_path)}" %>

and

    <%= link_to "All Stories", stories_path(featured: true), :class => "#{current_page(stories_path)}" %>

but both stories page and stories with params will have an active state..

Comment: What's your `current_page?` method?

Comment: Here is the method:

def current_page(path)
  "active" if current_page?(path)
end

Comment: Yeah, `current_page?` will return true for both `http://www.example.com/stories` and `http://www.example.com/stories?featured=true`

Comment: Right. Thats why I want to separate it based on request_uri.

Comment: Try the method I updated. It's not a perfect method, but I think it works.